# IE pop up when running powershell script

Tags: html, powershell, popup

There is the script what i want to run one of our server with a query user:

```
#HTML
$Wcl = new-object System.Net.WebClient
$Wcl.Headers.Add(“xxxx”, $xxxxxx)
$Wcl.Proxy.Credentials = [System.Net.CredentialCache]::DefaultNetworkCredentials
$html = Invoke-WebRequest -Uri https://www.mcafee.com/enterprise/en-us/downloads/security-updates.html
$dathtml = ($html.parsedhtml.getelementsbytagname("TR") |% { ( $_.children | ?{ $_.tagName -eq "td"} | % innerText ) } | Select-Object -First 1).Split('xdat')[0]
```

I get this window:

[TrustedZone](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T0F2y.jpg)

I already added to this site to the trusted zone but always get this window, I choose close and the sript running correctly.

How can I close this pop-up in power shell?

Thnaks for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Invoke-WebRequest](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/invoke-webrequest?view=powershell-5.1) will per default try and use Internet Explorer. However if you use the switch for basic parsing `-UseBasicParsing` you should be able to work around that so you don't use Explorer and thus doesn't run into Microsofts "Trusted Zones" requirement:

> -UseBasicParsing Indicates that the cmdlet uses the response object for HTML content without Document Object Model (DOM) parsing.
>
> This parameter is required when Internet Explorer is not installed on
>   the computers, such as on a Server Core installation of a Windows
>   Server operating system.

Try setting your invoke to this:

```
$html = Invoke-WebRequest -Uri https://www.mcafee.com/enterprise/en-us/downloads/security-updates.html -UseBasicParsing
```

Comment: Now my script looks like:

$html = Invoke-WebRequest -UseBasicParsing https://www.mcafee.com/enterprise/en-us/downloads/security-updates.html

and I get the following error message:

You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression.
At line:9 char:1
+ $dathtml = ($html.parsedhtml.getelementsbytagname("TR") |% { ( $_.chi ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvokeMethodOnNull
But I get correct data from the query.. Any idea? Thanks a lot!

Comment: You still need to use -URI for your URL.
I have updated my response with how it should look with the usebasicparsing switch